# Word usage: "answer me" or "answer to me"

Tags: word-usage

Given the phrase:

> Please, stop talking. I asked you a question.

Should one then add:

> Answer me, please **OR** Answer to me, please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally you say...

> Answer me, please

...if you are asking someone and only you both are in picture.

On the other hand, I can think of an example of

> Answer to me

Suppose you found one of your employees culprit. The scene includes the employee, boss, a sweeper and you. If you are asking something and if he's answering a sweeper, you can ***draw his attention*** by telling him, **Answer to me (not him)**. However, you put an accent on the pronoun *'me'* there (Thanks Araucaria).

*Answer to [someone]* also works when the context is 'reporting' to someone. It simply means, that *someone* is the boss as DavidRicherby gives his input.

*John answers to Jane* says that John reports to Jane as she's the boss.

Also, you can say **"my answer to him was no"** but then, it's an all different situation.

Comment: Great explanation! As always)

Comment: @Araucaria Oh, I too wanted to say that. How did I miss it! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Araucaria No. The credit should go to you. This is how a non-native like me learns. :)

Comment: Another usage of "answer to somebody" is that, in a corporate environment, "John answers to Jane" means that Jane is John's boss. You might also say that "politicians answer to their voters", meaning essentially the same thing.

Comment: @DavidRicherby indeed, worth including to improve the answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Nice comment.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it used mostly as "answer to" when the recipient is a person.
Ex.  *Answer to him/ Do not answer to them/
And just "answer" when there is no person involved; ie. Answer the door/Do not answer that letter, etc.*

Comment: This is wrong.  Answering a person and answering to a person are two expressions with very different meanings..